# Grid dashboard with Plotly dash

Tags: python, html, css, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to build a dashboard with Dash from Plotly composed of a series of tiles (Text) like in the picture below.

I'm trying to build a component to reuse it an build the layout below. Each box will contain a Title, a value and a description as shown below.

Is there a component available? Can someone help me with any basic idea/code ?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would recommend checking out [Dash Bootstrap Components](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/) (dbc).

You can use `dbc.Col` (columns) components nested into `dbc.Row` (rows) components to produce your layout. You can check them out [here](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/l/components/layout).

Then for the actual 'cards' as I'll call them, you can use the `dbc.Card` component. Here's the [link](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/l/components/card).

Here's some example code replicating your layout:

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_html_components as html

card = dbc.Card(
    dbc.CardBody(
        [
            html.H4("Title", id="card-title"),
            html.H2("100", id="card-value"),
            html.P("Description", id="card-description")
        ]
    )
)

layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([card]), dbc.Col([card]), dbc.Col([card]), dbc.Col([card]), dbc.Col([card])
    ]),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([card]), dbc.Col([card]), dbc.Col([card]), dbc.Col([card])
    ]),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([card]), dbc.Col([card])
    ])
])
```

Best thing would probably be to have a function which creates those cards with parameters for ids, titles and descriptions to save the hassle of creating different cards:

```
def create_card(card_id, title, description):
    return dbc.Card(
        dbc.CardBody(
            [
                html.H4(title, id=f"{card_id}-title"),
                html.H2("100", id=f"{card_id}-value"),
                html.P(description, id=f"{card_id}-description")
            ]
        )
    )
```

You can then just replace each `card` with `create_card('id', 'Title', 'Description')` as you please.

Another quick tip is that the `col` component has a parameter, `width`. You can give each column in a row a different value to adjust the relative widths. You can read more about that in the docs I linked above.

Hope this helps,

Ollie

Comment: That is very cool thanks! Do you know how can I do directly with HTML and CSS on Dash without using a third party library?

Comment: @jack87 Just using html and css will be a bit more of a pain. You'll need to look into using html divs and then styling the divs with float and clear css I believe (not 100% sure as I try to steer clear from as much html as I can while designing my dash apps).
I've started using dbc as if it's a standard part of Dash to be honest. Unless there is any restriction with you doing a simple pip install I would really really recommend using it. It cleans up your code a lot and covers a lot of functionality which would require separate stylesheets and more advanced html techniques etc.